# How to access row and column of an address?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The following all return 1:

```
=ROW(A1)
=ROW(A$1)
=ROW($A$1)
```

And

```
=ADDRESS(1,1)
```

returns $A$1 but if I try to enter

```
=ROW(ADDRESS(1,1))
```

Excel claims there is a problem with my formula.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ADDRESS(1,1)` returns a string/text.

> The ADDRESS function returns the address for a cell based on a given row and column number. For example, =ADDRESS(1,1) returns $A$1. ADDRESS can return a relative, mixed, or absolute reference, and can be used to construct a cell reference inside a formula. It's important to understand that the ADDRESS returns a reference as a text value. If you want to use this text inside a formula reference, you will need to coerce the text to a proper reference with the INDIRECT function.

Combine `ROW` function with the `INDIRECT` function to get the correct result.

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1)))
```